# Counting number of possible subtrees

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, dynamic-programming

Given an n-ary tree, how we can count number of all possible subtrees rooted at a particular node and containing atleast one edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse the tree via DFS and calculate the number of possible subtrees for every tree:

```
def _count_subtrees(node):
    result = 1

    # multiply the number of possibilities for each subtree
    # to get the total number of possible subtrees
    while node.has_more_children():
        result *= count_subtrees(node.next_child())

    # allow the empty subtree
    return result + 1

def count_subtrees(node):
    # two of the counted subtrees are invalid: the tree containing only
    # the root and the empty tree
    return _count_subtrees(node) - 2
```

The number of possible subtrees for a given node is the number of possible subtrees that can be built from all children multiplied with each other.

Consider three children, `a`, `b` and `c` of a node `n`, for which the sets of possible  subtrees are `A`, `B` and `C`. Then the set of possible subtrees for `n` is

```
N = { {n} x A x B x C } + {}
```

With cardinality `|N| = |A| * |B| * |C| + 1`.

Now for the root of the tree we need to eliminate two cases:

- the empty subtree
- the subtree that only contains `n`

Thus:

```
_S(leave) = 2   # two valid subtrees: empty tree and only 'leave'
_S(n) = S(c1(n)) * S(c2(n)) * ... + 1
S(n) = _S(n) - 2
```

Is the correct recurrence to calculate the number of possible subtrees for a given node